# Jquery- Check if class Exist inside a Div

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to check whther a class exists inside a div. But it is always resulting a length 0. Here is my Code :-

```
<div id="accordion2" class="accordion" >
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="align-nav arrow-active">OSTOMY PRODUCTS</div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Professional Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One-piece Pouching</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        <div class="align-nav arrow-inactive">LEARNING CENTER</div>
    </a> </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Before Your Surgery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
      <div class="align-nav">PROFESSIONAL RESOURCES </div>
    </a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
           <div class="align-nav">PROFESSIONAL RESOURCES </div>
    </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the First 2 div $(this).find('accordion-body').length should be 1. But it still show 0. My Jquery COde is as Follows :-

```
$('.accordion-heading').click(function() {
            if($(this).find('accordion-body').exist()) {
                alert('hi');
                if($(this).find('.collapsed').length > 0) {
                    alert('hi');
                    //$(this).find('.accordion-toggle .align-nav').removeClass('arrow-active').addClass('arrow-inactive');  
                }
                else {
                    alert('hi');
                    //$(this).find('.accordion-toggle .align-nav').removeClass('arrow-inactive').addClass('arrow-active');
                }
            }
        });
```

I need to get the $(this).find('accordion-body').length = 1; 
Please provide Solutions.

Comment: Please mention which `jQuery version` you are using

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should select a class selector (`.`) in `find` since you are searching for class

```
.find('.accordion-body')
     //^--- here
```

Also note that the `accordion-body` exists in parent div (next to the current element i.e this (`.accordion-heading`)) so use `parent()` or if you are sure it will always be the next div then you can use `.next`.

Try this

```
$(this).parent().find('.accordion-body').length == 1;
```

or you can use [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 1):

That would be `'.accordion-body'` (the period is vital -- it is the class selector).

Also `.exist()` is not a jQuery method, but I'll assume you've defined it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

You should find for siblings not the children, because `.accordion-body` is not a children of `.accordion-heading` it is a sibling instead.

```
    $('.accordion-heading').click(function() {
        if($(this).siblings('.accordion-body').length > 0) {
            alert('hi');
            if($(this).siblings('.collapsed').length > 0) {
                alert('hi');
                //$(this).find('.accordion-toggle .align-nav').removeClass('arrow-active').addClass('arrow-inactive');  
            }
            else {
                alert('hi');
                //$(this).find('.accordion-toggle .align-nav').removeClass('arrow-inactive').addClass('arrow-active');
            }
        }
    });
```

Issues were in your code:

1. `.exist()` is not a valid method to check any element
2. `$(this).find()` this finds the children not siblings at same level

Answer (score 0):

you are traversing in wrong context. Also try with latest jQuery and  [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
 $('#accordion2').on('click','.accordion-heading', function() {
        var accordionBodyLength = $(this).parent();
        var $accordBody = $('.accordion-body');
        alert(accordionBodyLength.find($accordBody).length);
  });
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/KhpXy/2)